# extract a phrase from excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In my excel sheet and in the column A,I have data filled from cell A2 to A100

and they all contain the data similar to the example below.

For example, in my Cell A2, what I would like to do is to only extract the

major.

*Cell A2 contents:*

**Institution :University Name**

**Degree :Diploma**

**Major :Teaching**

**Start date :01 Feb 2001**

**Completion date :31 Jul 2016**

Results that I am looking for :

**Major :Teaching**

Comment: The Data in A2 is only separated by space and Major is always just before Start date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each line in the cell is separated by a `LineFeed` character, as would usually be the case, then:

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("Major",A2),FIND(CHAR(10),A2,SEARCH("Major",A2))-SEARCH("Major",A2))
```

To elaborate on how this works, I will not explain how the different functions work -- MID, FIND, SEARCH and LEN since they are explained in Excel Help.  If you don't understand them, the explanation may not make sense.

```
MID(A2, startPoint_of "Major", length_of_the_whole_phrase)
SEARCH: Find the place where "Major" starts.  (case insensitive)
FIND:  Finding CHAR(10) which is the line feed character.
    Using the SEARCH "Major" term to define the starting point of the SEARCH, 
    so that it will be the linefeed that next follows "Major"
The difference between the startpoint of "Major" and the subsequent
    linefeed will be the length of the phrase
```

If you might want to find any of the components, you have to account for the fact that there may not be a line feed after the final line.  So for the part of the formula that is looking for the next linefeed, we surround it with an `IFERROR` function to replace that number with the length of the entire contents of A2, in case it does not find a line feed; and we also replace "Major" with a cell reference, so we can change what we are looking for.

The version of the formula below uses an absolute reference to refer to `A2`, but you may want to change that to a mixed form if you are going to drag the formula.

In the formula below, the Search Phrase would be entered in A4, and could be any of the line items.

```
=MID($A$2,SEARCH(A4,$A$2),IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),$A$2,SEARCH(A4,$A$2)),LEN($A$2))-SEARCH(A4,$A$2))
```

Comment: Could you please explain me how this function works?A friend of mine suggested me a similar one which worked fine also.

=MID(A2,SEARCH("Major",A2,1),(SEARCH(CHAR(10),RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("Major",A2,1)+1),1)))

Comment: I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula if the Data look the same like A2:

`=MID(A2,SEARCH("Major:",A2,1),SEARCH("Start",A2,1)-1-SEARCH("Major:",A2,1))`

you can copy `Major:` and `Start:` from your A2 in order to have the same spaces
You can drag the formula down